# Pdflatex on OSX El Capitan

Tags: pdftex, mac

I need to use pdfLaTeX. I installed the `BasicTeX.pkg` because the readme indicated it would contain `pdflatex`.

I have: `/Users/tmb/Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs`.

Which includes `texbin` - I tried to `cd` into `texbin` to look for `pdflatex` and I get

```
cd:cd:13: no such file or directory: texbin
```

I want to get pdfLaTeX and if possible without the full 2 + GB download how do I do this?

Comment: Welcome! It will be easier if you install in the default location. Is there some reason you can't do that? Also, where did you `cd` *from* exactly? Do you need pdfLaTeX for a very heavily constrained project? If so, Basic *might* work. If not, life will be much, much less frustrating if you install the full version. Is 2G really a problem?

Comment: I installed it using the Mactex package and this was the default location

Comment: Then you have a mutant package. The default installation location is under `/usr/local/texlive`. You will also get symbolic links created under `/Library/TeX/` but not anywhere in your home directory. (https://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html)

Comment: OK Found it under: /usr/local/texlive/2015basic  don't see anything in my path under Library it shows Library/TeX/Distributions/Programs and then an ls-al shows texbin -> ../.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin I think I need a path

Comment: That looks right. I don't know exactly what the links should be as I'm not on OS X but that looks very plausible. I'd assume it is correct unless somebody says otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean that you 'need a path'? What does `which pdflatex` give?

Comment: which pdflatex returns: pdflatex not found    Which is the problem the entire path is: /usr/local/texlive/2015basic/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex but if I add that to PATH it won't connect me with all the other files I'll need I believe that some texbin or ../.DefaultTeX/contents/Programs/texbin is wrong the Readme at https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf seems to indicate that inothing needs to be done fro the CLI apps